# Get div Source code to HTTP Post to Controller ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an MVC **view** in which I construct a **div** with some dynamic data.

```
<div>
   <p>Dynamic content</p>
</div>
```

Once the Div is finished rendering I want to hit a controller action method with a parameter of **( the inner source content of the div )**.

This is running in a web job so there is no user interaction to **click** a button.

I tried to post the div **inner HTML** content, which works fine.

```
document.getElementById("divContent").innerHTML
```

but I want this to happen after **div** has **finished rendering.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( "#DivId" ).load(function() {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Controller/Method',
            data: { ParamName: document.getElementById("DivId").innerHTML},
            success: function(result) {

            }
          });
        });
```

this event will fire when the div is loaded.